# inputmask for price using angularjs without using any plugin

Tags: angularjs

can anybody help me in writing a inputmask for formatting a price using angularjs without using any plugins.
i want if a user writes 56,then in the price field,it automatically comes a dot after 2nd digit and if the user enters only 56,then it display as 56.00.if somebody writes only a single digit 3(say),then it should come as 03.00.i need only 2 digit before dot and 2 digit after dot.

i have tried this,but it does not show a dot automatically after writing 2nd digit.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.phoneNumber;
    $scope.show = false;
    var count = 0;
    $scope.update = function(){

        var value = $scope.phoneNumber.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');
          if (value.match(/[^0-9.]/)) {
              $scope.phoneNumber = 0;
              $scope.show = true;
              return;
          }
          $scope.show = false;
          var pre, price, number ,post;

          switch (value.length) {
              case 1: // +1PPP####### -> C (PPP) ###-####
                  if(value == ".")
                  {
                    pre = "0";
                    price = 0;
                    number = 0;
                    post = 0;
                  }
                  else{
                  pre = 0;
                  price = value;
                  number = 0;
                  post = 0;
                  }
                  break;
              case 2: // +CPPP####### -> CCC (PP) ###-####
                  if(value[0] == ".")
                    {
                        pre = "0";
                        price = 0;
                        number = value[1];
                        post = 0;
                    }
                   else if(value[1] == ".")
                    {
                        pre = 0;
                        price = value[0];
                        number = 0;
                        post = 0;  
                    }
                  else
                  {
                        pre = value[0];
                        price = value[1];
                        number = 0;
                        post = 0;
                  }
                  break;

              case 3: // +CCCPP####### -> CCC (PP) ###-####
                  if(value[0] == ".")
                    {
                        pre = "0";
                        price = 0;
                        number = value[1];
                        post = value[2];
                    }
                   else if(value[1] == ".")
                    {
                        pre = 0;
                        price = value[0];
                        number = value[2];
                        post = 0;  
                    }
                    else if(value[2] == ".")
                    {
                        pre = value[0];
                        price = value[1];
                        number = 0;
                        post = 0;  
                    }
                  else
                  {
                        pre = value[0];
                        price = value[1];
                        number = value[2];
                        post = 0;
                  }
                  break;
              case 4:
                  if(value[0] == ".")
                    {
                        pre = "0";
                        price = 0;
                        number = value[2];
                        post = value[3];
                    }
                   else if(value[1] == ".")
                    {
                        pre = 0;
                        price = value[0];
                        number = value[2];
                        post = value[3];  
                    }
                    else if(value[2] == ".")
                    {
                        pre = value[0];
                        price = value[1];
                        number = 0;
                        post = value[3];  
                    }
                  else
                  {
                        pre = value[0];
                        price = value[1];
                        number = value[2];
                        post = value[3];
                  }
                  break;
              default:
                  pre = value[0];
                  price = value[1];
                  number = value[2];
                  post = value[3];
          }

          $scope.phoneNumber = (pre + price +"." + number + post).trim();

    };
  }])
```

Comment: Could you provide simple fiddle or update question with HTML template?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <input type="number" ng-model="price"/>
    Price: {{price | customNumber}}
</div>
```

### JS

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('customNumber', function($filter) {
    return function(input) {
        input = $filter('number')(input % 100, 2);
        return (input < 10) ? '0' + input : input;
    };
});
```

[live](http://jsfiddle.net/V56QG/2/)

Comment: no its not about using filter concept,its like inputmask concept of jquery.

Comment: I updated my answer and fiddle. Is that more like what you want to get?

Comment: its shows the output like 123444.00 or 12222.55 ,but i want it should show something like 12.55 that means,only 2 digit before dot and two digit after dot,but anyway you have done a great job.thank you very much

Comment: Updated again. Now the price can't get `>100`. You might add an exception for `=100` since the number filter might round `99.999`.